# FastAPI not saving data to MySQL Database

Tags: python, mysql, postman, fastapi

I'm creating a database that has a user database, and I'm trying to fill that table through a python developed API (FastAPI)

The relevant python code I have is:

```
class User(BaseModel):
    NOMBRE: str
    APELLIDOS: str
    USUARIO: str
    EMAIL: str
    NACIMIENTO: datetime.date
    SEXO: str
    ALTURA: float
    PESO: float

@app.post("/add_user")
def add_user(user: User):
    values = (user.NOMBRE, user.APELLIDOS, user.USUARIO, user.EMAIL, user.NACIMIENTO, user.SEXO, user.ALTURA, user.PESO)
    sql_query = "INSERT INTO Usuarios (Nombre, Apellidos, Usuario, Email, Nacimiento, Sexo, Altura, Peso) VALUES (%s, %s, %s, %s, %s, %s, %s, %s)"
    mycursor.execute(sql_query, values)
    return {"message": "Usuario Insertado"}
```

When I try to call this post method through Postman, I gives no issue, but the data is not added to the database (view images)

[Postman call](https://i.stack.imgur.com/meMaD.png)

[MySQL finds nothing](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4yn3c.png)

What am I missing?!?!?! I'm kinda rusty in programming and fairly new to APIs/Databases coding, and I don't even know what to search for or what to test. If I'm missing any information please let me know.

[MySQL Table Schema](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Tgq2x.png)

I have tried to include the values one by one, just in case I'm formatting something wrong, but no change of luck. I don't know what I am doing wrong.

Comment: Are you calling the database connection's `commit()` method anywhere? (It is not clear how the cursor and connection are managed from the code in the question).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are not using the `commit()` method in your function, so there are no actions in the DB.

Change your function like this:

```
@app.post("/add_user")
def add_user(user: User):
    values = (user.NOMBRE, user.APELLIDOS, user.USUARIO, user.EMAIL, user.NACIMIENTO, user.SEXO, user.ALTURA, user.PESO)
    sql_query = "INSERT INTO Usuarios (Nombre, Apellidos, Usuario, Email, Nacimiento, Sexo, Altura, Peso) VALUES (%s, %s, %s, %s, %s, %s, %s, %s)"
    mycursor.execute(sql_query, values)
    mycursor.commit()
    mycursor.close()
    return {"message": "Usuario Insertado"}
```

I also suggest to take a look at [SQLAlchemy](https://www.sqlalchemy.org/)
You can find more info here https://fastapi.tiangolo.com/tutorial/sql-databases/

Comment: Yep, I'm dumb, that was it. As a note, the commit method is not from the cursor, instead it is from the database connection

Comment: If anyone ends up in here:

I have declared in python a variable to connect to the database/table:

mydb = mysql.connector.connect(
    host="localhost",
    user="api_user",
    password="my-password",
    database="database"
)
So, the commit method has to be called from the "mydb" variable:

mydb.commit()-✅//
mycursor.commit()-❌

It will give you error saying that the Cursor has no atribute commit, and it is easy to find the error, but just in case.